# Indentation of boxes in Format.fprintf

Tags: formatting, format, ocaml

Please consider the function f:

```
open Format

let rec f i = match i with
  | x when x <= 0 -> ()
  | i ->
    pp_open_hovbox std_formatter 2;
    printf "This is line %d@." i; 
    f (i-1);
    printf "This is line %d@." i; 
    close_box ();
    ()
```

It recursively opens hovboxes and prints something, followed by a newline hint (@.). When I call the `f 3`, i obtain the following output:

```
This is line 3
This is line 2
This is line 1
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
```

but I expected:

```
This is line 3
  This is line 2
    This is line 1
    This is line 1
  This is line 2
This is line 3
```

Can you explain why I obtain the first output and what I need to change to obtain the second one?

Answer (score 4):

`@.` is not a newline hint, it is equivalent to [`print_newline`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Format.html#VALprint_newline) which calls [`print_flush`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Format.html#VALprint_flush) which closes all opened boxes and follows by a new line.

If you want to print line by line with `Format` you should open a vertical box with [`open_vbox`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Format.html#VALopen_vbox) and use [`print_cut`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Format.html#VALprint_cut) (`"@,"`) whenever you want to output a new line.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that print_flush closes the box.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `@.` you should use `@\n` specificator. The former, will flush the formatter and output a hard newline, actually breaking your pretty printing. It is intended to be used at the end of document, and, since it is not actually composable, I would warn against using it at all.

With `@\n`, you will get an output that is much closer to what you're expecting:

```
This is line 3
  This is line 2
    This is line 1
      This is line 1
      This is line 2
    This is line 3
```

The same output, by the way, can be obtained by using `vbox` and emitting `@;` good break hints, that is better.

Comment: Thank you too! Is there a way to get an indentation for the first line without adding a ```@\n```?